# for(i in seq_along(data_file): Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

Tags: r

I begin by reading data into R via an Excel file which contains a list of file location and file names:

```
data_files <- readxl::read_excel("./Data/source_data.xlsx")
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Next I want to iterate over this list using a for loop/seq_along to access each row variable and use the row variable within the read.csv() and then do things:

```
for(i in seq_along(data_files)){
  x <- read.csv(data_files[[i]], sep= "\t", skipNul = TRUE)
  # DO THINGS
}
```

When I run the for loop, I get:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I know it has to do with the iteration not occurring in a manner that I expect because when I do the following the csv is read into R successfully:

```
path <- "/Users/gerb/Downloads/"
file <- "Who_Has_Seen_crosstab (2).csv"
path_file <- paste(path, file, sep="")

x <- read.csv(path_file, sep= "\t", skipNul = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you really need an image in this post, can you just cut/paste the R output ? What iteration of the loop does it fail on ? What is the text for the item it fails on ?

Comment: @steveb, "do you really need an image".. no "can you just cut/paste the R output", yeah.  "What iteration of the loop does it fail on" doesn't process anything.

Comment: `for(f in data_files[[1]])`{x <- read.csv(f, sep= "\t", skipNul = TRUE); DO STUFF}`.

Comment: Tip: in cases like this you can save a lot of time if you `print(data_files[[i]])` just before calling `read.csv`. You would have seen ***the entire column vector*** printed when `i == 1`. Try it now, if you doubt it.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

@Rui Barradas gets my vote but it is worth expanding on his answers. from `?seq_along` : "seq_along and seq_len return an integer vector." As mentioned you can see this by adding print into a function.

```
l = tibble(a = c("a","b","C"))
x = tibble(a = c("a","b","C"),
            b = c("x","y","z"))

for(i in seq_along(l)){
    print(l[i])
}

# A tibble: 3 x 1
   a    
 <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 C 


for(i in seq_along(x)){
    print(x[i])
 }

> for(i in seq_along(x)){
      print(x[i])
   }

 #A tibble: 3 x 1
 a    
<chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 C    
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  b    
 <chr>
1 x    
2 y    
3 z
```

You don't want the entire vector. It seems that you want to iterate over each row in a tibble. There are others ways to do this, but something like this would be a better approach:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(l)){
    print(l[i,])
  }

# A tibble: 1 x 1
 a    
<chr>
1 a    
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  a    
 <chr>
1 b 
 .....
```

Last point: it is easier to read a copy and paste of R output than a image. Avoiding screen grabs for future questions would be helpful for others.